# Remote Diagnostics of Client PC's

Tags: remote

I have an army of PoS (Point-of-Sale) client machines in the field.  Most have an IP connection to the server.

My challenge though is logging remote diagnostics from these machines.

Things like temperature, fan speed, etc. to gauge the health of the hardware and be more proactive in support before a machines fails.

I'm looking for a software solution that would allow me to gather such various information from these machines and put it into my server database.  After which I can then review the logged data and check the health of my client PC's, from my desk.

Does anyone have experience with such a challenge?

(Windows based)

Comment: What Operating System does this software need to run on?

Comment: This is a Windows based network.

Comment: Are they all from the same vendor e.g. all HPs or Dells? If so, there are system auditing and management tools available from suppliers, usually at no cost.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specfic hardware you can monitor lots of data through WMI.  Some network monitoring systems like Zenoss combined with some addon packs can even graph data over time.

If you don't want/need a full network monitor, you could build some scripts and log the data into [RRDtool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool)

- [Fan status](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/cf1e5fb1-e84c-4145-a44b-d276294f5901)
- [CPU Temperature](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/18ce0701-e87d-4414-a8b5-8be3908a21b8)

Answer (score 1):

I have done exactly this with POS system of over 100 POS terminals with Nagios. The terminals ran Win2K or XP. The monitoring server was just an old desktop PC running Linux.

It's a bit of pain for the initial setup and figuring out what and how you want to monitor the terminals. We made a zip package with a batch file that we would just run on the terminal that would do the setup, then add a line to Nagios telling it to location of the terminal.

Comment: NRPE/NSCP makes deployment a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

[Samurize](http://www.samurize.com/modules/news/) offers real-time monitoring for any host (as long as youre creative enough). Logging the data to a DB will require some tricky implementation, however.